# Appium automation not working correctly on intelx86 based emulator

Tags: android, python, android-emulator, appium, haxm

I have an automation script using appium-python-client which run fine on 
following configuration of the android emulator:

1. target:Google APIs -API level 19
2. CPU:ARM

but this was too slow. So I switched to new emulator with following configuration

1. target:Google APIs(x86 System Image)-API level 19
2. CPU:Intel Atom (x86)

This is very fast in booting and everything. But my script fails randomly and passes once in a while with following reasons

1. The app screen loaded incompletely (when I minimise and maximise manually it appears correctly, so element could not be found). More Details: screen loads half only.
2. driver.click() passed but effect not visible on Emulator UI (so element could not be found). More details: UI freezes. Can even click manually. When I minimise and maximise then it appears to be responsive.

How can these issues be resolved? I added `implicitwait` but that didn't help either. The same steps work fine in `arm` based `cpu` but not in `intel` based. I have even installed the `hotfix` for Intel x86.

Comment: `implicitlyWait()` would wait for the specified time unless the element is not found, otherwise the execution proceeds without a wait. You can implement an explicit wait `WebDriverWait` and try.

Comment: could you specify the details to "The app screen loaded incompletely"  and "driver.click() passed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things,I disabled `Use Host GPU` in my intel x86 emulator and it now works fine.FYI

[image]